# Fluid access other array in for loop

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

I have to arrays like:

```
$business = array(0 => 'Car', 1 => 'IT');
$counts   = array(0 => 15, 1 => 33);
```

I assign both array in my fluid template and iterate over the array business.

```
<f:for each="{business}" as="b" key="key">
    <li>
        <f:link.action action="business" arguments="{current_business: b.uid}">
            <f:if condition="{counts.key} > 0">
                <f:then>
                    {b.title} {counts.key}
                </f:then>
                <f:else>
                    {b.title}
                </f:else>
             </f:if>
        </f:link.action>
    </li>
</f:for>
```

I don't get an ouput for `{counts.key}`, should i access this an other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done using the [`v:variable.get`-ViewHelper](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Variable/GetViewHelper.html) from the extension [`vhs`](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/vhs). Instead of `{counts.key}` use

```
{v:variable.get(name: 'counts.{key}')}
```

or

```
<v:variable.get name="counts.{key}"/>.
```

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can do it as Jost showed by manipulating data within the view , it's perfectly valid, on the other hand probably combining arrays within your controllers into associative array(s) will be just more comfortable, like:

```
$business = array(
    0 => array('title' => 'Car', 'count' => '15'),
    1 => array('title' => 'IT', 'count' => '33'),
);
```

view

```
<f:for each="{business}" as="b">
    <li>
        <f:link.action action="business" arguments="{current_business: b.uid}">
            <f:if condition="{b.count} > 0">
                <f:then>
                    {b.title} ({b.count})
                </f:then>
                <f:else>
                    {b.title} (no items)
                </f:else>
             </f:if>
        </f:link.action>
    </li>
</f:for>
```

Note: If in real case that's a collection of model objects, you can just add `transient` - `count` field into your model - without TCA and SQL declarations - in this case you will be able to set values "on the fly" on this field within the controller and use them as common model field in the views but they won't be saved to DB.